# Multiplication large numbers in perl

Tags: perl, multiplication

i have a problem with a scripts below and How to make multification results equals to 1332521814089765.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $divide = 1332521814089765/1332521809;
my $results1 = int $divide;
print "After Divide: $results1 \n";

my $multiplication = $results1*1332521809;
my $results2 = $multiplication;
print "After Multiplication: $results2 \n"; #How to make multification results equals to 1332521814089765
```

after searching and make a test  here the results but still not get my expected results

```
my $divide = 1332521814089765/1332521809;
my $multiplication = $divide*1332521809;
my $results = $multiplication/10;
print "My     Results: $results\nExpect Results: 1332521814089765\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1000000 * 1332521809 is equal to 1332521809000000. Why would you expect 1332521814089765?

Maybe you are multiplying the wrong numbers, which is to say you meant to use

```
 my $multiplication = $divide*1332521809;
```

instead of

```
 my $multiplication = $results1*1332521809;
```

---

Another possibility is that you are trying to find the inverse function of

```
$y = int($x/$k)
```

Unfortunately, there is none because there are multiple values of `$x` that give the same `$y`.

```
int(1332521809000000/1332521809) = 1000000
...
int(1332521814089764/1332521809) = 1000000
int(1332521814089765/1332521809) = 1000000
int(1332521814089766/1332521809) = 1000000
...
int(1332523141521808/1332521809) = 1000000
```

Comment: Why would i expect 1332521814089765?  because This number (1332521809) is timestamp. So i do not know how this number came out 1332521814089765 and try to make a formula how to get my expect numbers

Comment: @user681451, That's not what I asked. I asked why do you expect 1000000 * 1332521809 to give 1332521814089765. To get the expected number, you need to use the correct inputs.

Comment: @user681451, If you're trying to find the inverse function of `int`, there is none. It is a lossy function.  e.g. `$x` in `int($x)=5` could be 5.2, 5.3, etc.

Comment: i expect 1000000 * 1332521809 to give 1332521814089765 because after dividing 1332521814089765 / timestamp i get 1000000 so i think after multiplication it will also give 1332521814089765

Comment: @user681451, No, you did not get 1000000 after dividing (`$divide`). You got 1000000 from `int` (`$results1`). See updated answer.  Seriously, do the math. Eight year olds can do 1000000 * 1332521809 in their head, and they know it doesn't give 1332521814089765.

Comment: i think i need to multiplication $timestamp with 11 days, 13 hours, 46 minutes and 40 seconds. then i get the results that i expected. Because 10000000 = 11 days, 13 hours, 46 minutes and 40 seconds is that right

Comment: @user681451, There is nothing you can multiply to `int($x/1332521809)` that will get you `$x`, as discussed in my answer.

Comment: Okay i change the scripts but still not get my expected results. why?

Comment: @user681451, What result do you get?